# Is arr, *arr, arr[0] and &arr[0][0] the same in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i find some similar questions but not this...

if I got this:

```
 double B[3][3] = {{1.,0.,0.},{0.,1.,0.},{0.,0.,1.}};
```

then:

`B`, `*B`, `B[0]`, and `&B[0][0]`

are the same?

for example, if i create this method:

```
void suma(double A[][3], double *B, double *C);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     double A[3][3] = {{1.,2.,3.},{4.,5.,6.},{7.,8.,9.}};
     double B[3][3] = {{1.,0.,0.},{0.,1.,0.},{0.,0.,1.}};
     double C[3][3];

     suma(A, &B[0][0], C[0]);

     return 0;
}

void suma(double A[][3], double *B, double *C){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            *(C+i*3+j) = A[i][j] + *(B+i*3+j);
        }
    }
}
```

I can call the function with the 4 diferents ways, and work all

Comment: Use `printf("%p\n", (void *)B); printf("%p\n", (void *)*B);` ... and so on and see yourself,  `%p` is the format specifier to print an address

Comment: Thanks David!  didn't know about the %p

Comment: `*B`, `B[0]` and `&B[0][0]` are equivalent. However, `B` is not. It is equivalent to `&B[0]`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `B[0]` and `&B[0][0]` are not equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C an array under most situations can decay to a pointer to the first element of the array. So:

- `B` is of type `double[3][3]` an decays to `double (*)[3]` (pointer to array of 3 doubles)
- `*B` and `B[0]` are identical and are of type `double[3]` (array of 3 doubles) and decay to `double *` (pointer to double).
- `&B[0][0]` is of type `double *`.

And then there are function parameters: In C arrays cannot be function parameters. So when used as the type of a function parameter what looks like an array is not an array, but it is in fact a pointer, ignoring the first array dimension, e.g.:

```
void foo(double arr[3])
void foo(double arr[])
```

Are in reality:

```
void foo(double* arr)
```

The same is true for multidimensional arrays:

```
void foo(double arr[2][3])
void foo(double arr[][3])
```

Are in reality:

```
void foo(double (*arr)[3])
```

---

With the above in mind let's go through **your examples**:

```
void foo(double p[][3]);
// is actually:
void foo(double (*p)[3]);

foo(A);
```

`A` decays to `double (*)[3]` which is the expected parameter type. So everything is ok.

```
void foo(double* p);

foo(&B[0][0])
```

No problems here either, you directly pass a pointer to the first double element.

```
void foo(double* p)

foo(C[0]);
```

`C[0]` is of type `double[3]` and decays to `double*` which is the expected parameter type. Again, ok.

Answer (score 2):

No, `B`, `*B`, `B[0]`, and `&B[0][0]` are not the same.

Their types are different:

- `B`: array 3 of array 3 of double
- `*B`: array 3 of double
- `B[0]`: array 3 of double
- `&B[0][0]`: pointer to double

When you allow them to decay to pointers (the fourth item is already a pointer), the types are still different:

- `B`: pointer to array 3 of double
- `*B`: pointer to double
- `B[0]`: pointer to double
- `&B[0][0]`: pointer to double

Since the pointer to an array is equivalent to the pointer to its first element, these four expressions have the same value.

Note that the last 3 have the same type. These are completely equivalent. The type of the first holds more information. It "knows" that there are groups of 3 doubles.

This type difference can be shown by running the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double B[3][3] = {
    { 1., 0., 0. },
    { 0., 1., 0. },
    { 0., 0., 1. }
};

int main() {
    printf("%p: %zu\n", (void *) B, sizeof(*B));
    printf("%p: %zu\n", (void *) (*B), sizeof(*(*B)));
    printf("%p: %zu\n", (void *) (B[0]), sizeof(*(B[0])));
    printf("%p: %zu\n", (void *) (&B[0][0]), sizeof(*(&B[0][0])));
}
```

Which, for me, output:

```
0x404040: 24
0x404040: 8
0x404040: 8
0x404040: 8
```

You can see that the first item is different in that the elements to which it points have a size three times that of the other items.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**: They have the same value.

This C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()

{

    double arr[3][3] = {{1.,0.,0.},{0.,1.,0.},{0.,0.,1.}};


    printf("arr=%p \n", arr);
    printf("*arr=%p \n", *arr);
    printf("arr[0]=%p \n", arr[0]);
    printf("&arr[0][0]=%p \n", &arr[0][0]);
```

}

says:

```
arr=0x7ffc17d4dba0 
*arr=0x7ffc17d4dba0 
arr[0]=0x7ffc17d4dba0 
&arr[0][0]=0x7ffc17d4dba0
```

Comment: Note that your arguments for `"%p"` format specifiers must be of type `void *`. For this code to not invoke undefined behavior, you have to cast those arguments with `(void *)`. Also, as the other answers note, these four things are not the same, even if they all effectively point to the same thing.

Comment: Too bad that even `gcc -Wall` (gcc 4.8.5) does not  detect it.

Comment: Turning on `-Wall -pedantic` will show these as warnings.

Comment: And it does also show following warnings on your code: 
`Warning: ISO C90 does not support the 'z' gnu_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
`

Comment: Only if you're compiling for a version of C as old as ISO C90. Compiling for C99, which is the oldest that's commonly used, there are no errors. Adding `-std=c99` adds the `z` length modifier and an implicit `return 0;` to `main`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you are saying about the record `arr` you mean using the array designator in expressions. In this case it is implicitly converted (with rare exceptions as for example using in the operator `sizeof`) to pointer to its first element and has the type `double ( * )[3]`.

This expression `*arr` yields the lvalue of the first element of the array that is the element arr[0] that has the type `double[3]`. Again used in expressions this array designato is converted to pointer to its firs element that has the type double. It is the same as to write `&arr[0][0]`.

Shorter saying all three expression will yield the same value - the address of the extent memory occupied by the array but has different types.

So used in expressions (with rare exception) where the implicit conversion from an array to pointer to its first element takes place these records have the following types

`arr`  has the type `double( * )[3]`

`*arr`  has the type `double *`.

`arr[0]` is the same as `*arr` and has the same type `double *`.

`&arr[0][0]` is the same as `arr[0]` and `*arr` and has the type `double *`.

**Edit:** After you appended your question with a program code then in this call

```
 suma(A, &B[0][0], C[0]);
```

the first argument expression A has the type `double( * )[3]` the second argument expression has the type `double *` and the third argument expression also has the type `double *`.

In fact within the function you reinterpreted two-dimensional arrays B and C as one dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`B` denotes the array of three arrays of three `double`. When used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So it will act as if it were `&B[0]`.

In `*B`, `B` acts as above; it acts as `&B[0]`. So `*B` is `*&B[0]`, which is `B[0]`. This denotes the array of three `double` that is the first such array in `B`. When used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So it will act as if it were `&B[0][0]`.

`B[0]` is as explained above.

`&B[0][0]` is the address of the first element in the first array of `B`.

Thus `*B`, `B[0]`, and `&B[0][0]` are all equivalent except when used as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`.

However, `B` is different. `B` is the address of an array, whereas the others are the address of a `double`. These addresses refer to the same location in memory, because that `double` is the first element in the array, so it starts in the same place the array starts. However:

- They have different types. `B` is, after the automatic conversion, a pointer to an array, whereas `*B`, `B[0]`, and `&B[0][0]` are pointers to a `double`. C has rules about how types may be used, and you should not use one type where an incompatible type is expected.
- They may have different representations. Many C implementations use a flat address space in which addressed are formed simply by numbering bytes in memory. However, they may have more complicated addressing schemes, and the values for `B` and `B[0]` (both after conversion) may have different representations and might not be interchangable.
- They may behave differently in expressions. For example, `B+1` and `B[0]+1` will yield pointers to different places, because `B+1` will point to the second array in `B` (which starts with `B[1][0]`), whereas `B[0]+1` will point to the second element in `B[0]` (`B[0][1]`).

Answer (score 1):

When used in expressions (except for example as operand of the `sizeof` operator):

`B` - is a pointer to an array of 3 `double`, `double (*)[3]` -  Nonetheless it gains the address of the first element of the first array.

`*B` - is a pointer to double , `double *`- Actually a pointer to the first element in the first array.

`B[0]` - is a pointer to double, `double *` - Actually a pointer to the first element in the first array.

`&B[0][0]` - is a pointer to double, `double *` - Actually a pointer to the first element in the first array.

There are not the same. `B` has a different type. - However, they all actually have the same result. - The evaluation to the address of the first element in the first array.